# WCF Services on shared hosting (This collection already contains an address with scheme http.)

Tags: wcf, shared-hosting

When trying to call a WCF service I receive the following error:

```
This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. 
Parameter name: item
```

The Goog tells me that the solution is as follows (when using .net 3.5, which I am):

```
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters> 
    <add prefix="http://mydomain.com.au"/> 
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
```

However, when I try to add this to the  section of my web.config it tells me it is invalid.

Comment: I have the similar problem...can u help me?

[My question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152348/windows-service-on-shared-windows-hosting

Answer (score 0):

You should use this instead in 3.5:

```
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

if you move to 4.0 you can use svc less activation as shown here:
[ServiceRoute + WebServiceHostFactory kills WSDL generation? How to create extensionless WCF service with ?wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921802/serviceroute-webservicehostfactory-kills-wsdl-generation-how-to-create-extens)

Comment: I tried multipleSiteBindingsEnabled earlier and it says "Attribute not allowed".  I would use .net 4 but my host only supports 3.5.  I miss having my own dedicated server :(

Comment: i just noticed multipleSiteBindingsEnabled is a 4.0 feature.  Your going need to do this with code (I remember having a similar problem and finding an wcf extension that supported this)  however try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508892/multiple-base-addresses-in-single-wcf-service