# Javascript + SQL, .NET

Tags: javascript, .net, sql-server, ajax

Okay, this will probably get closed or get some negative replies, but I've been trying to get this going for 3 nights and I'm extremely frustrated.

I have a shared .net host (1and1.com).  I'm trying to develop a webapp that primarily uses javascript/jquery.  I have data in a MS SQL database.  I cannot use Ajax to call a WCF service to do my database queries because there is some stupid limitation with multiple IIS hostheaders which affects people on shared hosts such as mine.

So, I'm looking  for recommendations for alternatives.  The really tricky part is that I'm not great at learning programming concepts; I'm really more of a copy/paste pirate (I do my job well and have hundreds of happy customers, for the record).  But I do admit it's a major handicap.  As such, it would be unbelievably helpful if any answers could include simple, yet complete, code examples.

I am using .net 3.5, the current version of JQuery and SQL Server 2005, and VB syntax (sorry).

Please and thank you.

Comment: Well, at least your honest I guess lol

Comment: Yeah, blame it on my ADD, but when someone posts an answer like "Look up MethodX", I google it and read about 20 lines and then wake up an hour later drooling.  Then I go back to find more sample code that does what I want.

Comment: Can you add a link to some article explaining the exact problem of WCF on shared hosting environments?

Comment: @RemusRusanu: http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=This+collection+already+contains+an+address+with+scheme+http.

Comment: And remus, before you recommend BaseAddressPrefixFilters, please check this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801674/wcf-services-on-shared-hosting-this-collection-already-contains-an-address-with

Comment: That wasn't supposed to sound as curt as it did :)

Comment: How about http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rampo/archive/2008/02/11/how-can-wcf-support-multiple-iis-binding-specified-per-site.aspx ? It includes 3.0 and 3.5 (there isa  second step in 3.5, besides the baseAddressPrefix fix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, WCF is overly complex for simple web service scenarios. I would highly recommend using Page Methods instead. Dave Ward has a great article on how to do this on his blog.

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: hmm, looks simple, other than the pagemethod itself being in C.  I'll give it a go tonight, maybe look up sample vb page methods.  Thanks.  will accept later if appropriate.

Comment: I'm with you, but i'd say asp.net mvc is a much better way to go in most scenario's. It is so easy to do ajax with.

Comment: Ended up getting an ASMX to work. This got me there though and I'm sure it works (if you're not me) so I'll accept it.  Thanks.