# Windows Service on Shared Windows Hosting

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, web-services, shared-hosting

I have process which continuously downloads **XML** from the feed and saves it to **DB**.
I  have a **Windows Shared Hosting**.

My question is what should I use..**WCF** or **Windows Service** or **Web Service**.

I cant use ASP.net because it will run on call only...but I need it run **24/7**.
Can you guyz suggest me how to design it?

I have written a Windows Service but was unable to run it on the Server.

My hosting provider is **Hostgator.com**

Comment: If you can't run a Windows service, can you run scheduled tasks on the host?

Comment: Schedule Tasks take place every minute....but my process make calls every second.

Comment: Yes, but you could make a scheduled task make a request to an URL on the local machine, and do the work in the script it triggers. Likely, it will time out occasionally so you have to have a scheduled task to restart it every minute or so. It's not as good a solution as a Windows service, but if you can't run 'em, you can't run 'em.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in a Windows Service.
To run it you'll need a VPS hosting (or dedicated, but it will cost much more).

Start with building a Console Application that does what you need. After you have it look online how to convert it to a windows service.

Comment: Cant I do it Shared Hosting Service...I cant afford VPS.

Comment: @faisal00813 - Shared Hosting is for Web Hosting, you can't run your Windows Service on it.

Comment: What about WCF...or Web Service..can I achieve my requirements via 'em

Comment: No if you need something to run 24/7. The only overpass you can do is to implement is as WCF or WebSite and have another computer(client) to make it run all the time.